# Why is my macro only populating formula in first row and not filling column of table?

Tags: excel, excel-tables

I have a macro that formats cells and populates formulas in a workbook. When testing this on a small scale, the macro worked great as it would insert the formulas in row 2 of table and table would autofill formula to bottom.
I looked to use this on a .csv import which i have converted to a table. The macro is populating row 2 but the table is not autofilling it to bottom as it normally does with formulas and as it did in my simple test. I get the feeling this is something simple i am overlooking and not a result of the Macro, hoping someone has an idea of what setting to check in excel?
Thanks

Comment: Without the actual source code of the macro, you can't expect us to have an idea :-)

Comment: When a formula is entered into the first row of a table, it (usually) automatically populates to the bottom row of the table.  I was wondering if any settings in excel to double check? The macro is quite large, it has worked on a smaller table of 5 rows, therefore, perhaps over-optimistically, i had hoped it would be a setting issue to verify rather than the macro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such autofill feature works in a table only. First, you need to convert the range to a table:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange,Range("$F$2:$H$13"),,xlNo).Name = _
           "Table2"
```

Second, the row (data area) where a formula is entered should be empty. Third, you should enter a formula to the topmost cell (below header) of the row.

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful, much appreciated.

Comment: Excel is the excellent app for developers. First you can proceed all actions manually. Then you can record your actions. And finally, you can adjust the code.